# Printing an arraylist in java with numbers in front

Tags: java, eclipse, for-loop, arraylist

I want an output format like this:

[[image]

But I get this instead:

[image]

Where is my error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You keep re-initializing `counter` instead of initializing it before and incrementing it inside the loop.
That is why `counter == 1` *always*.
So what you need to do is take the `int counter=1;` outside the `for` loop, and put `counter++;` inside the loop where your previous statement was.

Comment: that's it. thanks very much but i blackout some times xD